# IndexError :tuple index out of range

Tags: python, django

I have a dictionary which contains a list and the list elements are supposed to be tuple

I am creating a product filter from filter.py I am sending the tuple as per the user choice in URL and in views.py

```
qu=dict(request.GET)
#qu={'price':['(300,600)']}
```

I want to run the following query

```
result=Product.objects.all()

for key, value in qu.items():
    result=result.filter(attribute__price__range=value)

print (result)
```

I am getting IndexError :tuple index out of range

Comment: Those are strings so something is off... can you post the full error stack trace in your question?

Comment: How are you getting the value of `qu` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the ast module.

**Ex:**

```
import ast
qu={'price':['(300,600)']}
for value in qu['price']:
    result=result.filter(attribute__price__range=ast.literal_eval(value))
```

Comment: I am getting ValueError: malformed node or string: ['(300, 600)']

Comment: Are you using `for value in qu['price']:` ?